# KnockoutJs: 2d observable array to table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, knockout.js

I want to create a table of input fields in html using the observable array feature of knockoutJs. As my html-file, I have got this:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: textFields">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
        <td><input data-bind="value: $data"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(Of course this is not the whole html, but the relevant part.)

As the knockout file, I have got this:

```
function MatrixViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.textFields = ko.observableArray([[0, 0], [0, 0]]);
}
ko.applyBindings(new MatrixViewModel());
```

According to what I understand, what should happen si that the table gets each of the arrays in the textFields array, i.e. [0, 0] and [0, 0]. Then for each of those a table row is created. This table row takes each of the values, i.e. 0 and 0 and creates a td for each of them. Then inside the td the value is used for the input field.

But what I get is just one lonely input field sitting on the screen. So something must be wrong with my code/my understanding. Can anyone tell me what?

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with the code you provided - [here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XN5MM/) with your code copy/pasted that produces a 2x2 grid of input boxes for me. I guess there is something wrong in the code you didn't provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was the placement of the script tags. I had to place them after the body, not before.

Comment: Could you accept your answer so that this question does not show a s unanswered?

Comment: I can only do that two days after I answered.

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't know